# How to replace values of a column in one MySQL table with values of a column in another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table named as data1 with two columns (Name, address) and an another table named as data2 with same columns

My question: How to assign the address column of data2 to address column of data1 where the value in name columns are equal in both the tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
update data1 d1
inner join data2 d2 on
    d2.name = d1.name
set d1.address = d2.address
```

To be sure it's updating the rows you want to update, it's a good idea to do a select with the join before running the update:

```
select * from data1 d1
 inner join data2 d2 
  on d2.name = d1.name
```

Comment: I do not want to loose the columns that are not the same. would this query only get the identical columns and update the table?

Comment: Wherever d2.name = d1.name, it will set d1.address equal to d2.address

Comment: Yes, only the columns explicitly named in the set statement will be updated.

Answer (score 0):

did u tried this query

UPdate (talbe_name) SET (colname) = 'xxx'
where (col name_id)= table id